# How to open a new tab in the same browser by using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I can open a new window with Selenium WebDriver by using Java and JavaScript. I am using Firefox. The code is as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("function createDoc(){var w = window.open(); w.document.open(); w.document.write('<h1>Hello World!</h1>'); w.document.close();}; createDoc();");
```

How can I open a new tab in the same browser by using WebDriver (Selenium 2)?

Comment: You can try this

[Open url in new tab using javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4907843

Comment: @Hamon: I tried the following: jse.executeScript("function createDoc(url){window.open(url, '_blank');}; createDoc(this.href);"); Same thing was happened, i.e., a new window was opened instead of new tab [Note: my concern is to open new tab, NOT new window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasim,

```
cdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
```

You can use above line to open new tab in a same browser (Works in Firefox)

Comment: Hi Suresh, It's really a better answer. It's working as my desired. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard support in JavaScript or HTML for opening a link in a tab vs a window. It's depending on browser and settings. Some browsers default to opening in new tabs (like Chrome and Safari). Some browser allows the user to configure the behavior. Bottom line, you shouldn't design your site to rely on opening new windows in tabs as there is no reliable and cross-browser compatible mechanism for doing that.

Comment: That is, there is no extra/additional code for opening new tab, right am I? Is it possible to do by configuring browser set up?

Comment: Some browsers allow you to specify if new windows (window.open or target="_blank") should be opened in a new window or a new tab. In Firefox you can set it under Tools->Options->Tabs, for instance.

Comment: thanks. I have set up Tabs from Tools->Options->Tabs, but unfortunately Selenium 2 (WebDriver) failed to open a new tab instead of a new window

Comment: Like I said, it's not predictable. I have no idea how Selenium interacts with Firefox with regards to these settings. Don't rely on consistent behavior with regards to tabs and don't design sites with expectations that it should behave one way or the other when opening new windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly depends on your browser settings and there is no separate methods for opening link in new window or new tab

Comment: How can I configure the browser to open a new tab?

Comment: In firefox go to options and then go to options for tabs and choose there open new window in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
original_window = browser.current_window_handle
browser.switch_to.new_window('tab')
browser.get(some_url)
#do stuff
browser.close()
browser.switch_to.window(original_window)
```

Answer (score -1):

It also depends on how your browser is configured to open pop-up's.

Comment: How can I configure the browser to open pop up?