# How to open a new tab using selenium webdriver using Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open a new tab using Selenium Webdriver and Java, and have used the below code, but it is not opening any new tab and no error message is displayed during the run.

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);      
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("t").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

Using the above code I am trying to open a new tab by pressing CTRL+T from keyboard. Please help me.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139173/how-to-open-a-new-tab-in-the-same-browser-by-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java?rq=1

Comment: You are sending Keys.CONTROL twice

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("urlLink")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

or use

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open();");
```