# How to open a new tab in the same browser by using Selenium WebDriver with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I want to open a new tab in the current session of the Selenium WebDriver using Python. I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139173/how-to-open-a-new-tab-in-the-same-browser-by-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java) for Java but could not convert it to Python. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link that you have posted uses a keyboard shortcut to open the new tab. You can try manually using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> this shortcut opens a new tab in the current browser. So here is what we have to do:

Locate an element using Web-Driver and send it the shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).

```
import from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_to_one_element').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL +"t")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a duplicate of this, here is what they suggest:

[Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python)

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

On Windows you would use `CONTROL + T`